# Jquery scroll

Tags: jquery, javascript, прокрутка

Привет всем! Есть такая проблема

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$(this).scroll( function () { alert('scrolled'); })

})
```

Это работает

```
$(document).ready( function () {

$('#myblock').scroll( function () { alert('scrolled'); })

})
```

А это не работает! Кто знает почему?

**Обновление**

```
<html!>
<head>
/.../
<style>
    #mycontainer { position:absolute;height:500px;overflow:hidden;}
    #myblock { position:relative;overflow:auto;}

</style>
</head>

    <div id="mycontainer">
        <div id="myblock">
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Примерно такой

**Обновление 2**

http://jsfiddle.net/93vbspwq/ , но яваскрипт почему-то не видно.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).scroll( function () {
   alert('docscrolled')
    })
    $('#myblock').scroll( function () {
   alert('blockscrolled')

    })

})
```

Эххх в последнее время здесь труднее получить помощь(( все сам починил, причина в том что для работы этой функции нужно указать фиксированную высоту прокручиваемого элемента.Все равно спасибо всем кто откликнулся

Comment: Для полноты картины не мешало б увидеть html и css.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Вы считаете, это может быть связано с позиционированием?

Comment: если покажешь тут [link](http://jsfiddle.net/) - может и помогу

Comment: @stas56, оба кода [рабочие][1]. Ищите проблему в другом месте. И в первую очередь - в консоли, которая на время отладки, у вас вообще не должна закрываться.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/93vbspwq/1/

Comment: Как в другом месте? Я создаю пустой документ, в котором только это, и все.

Comment: > пустой документ, в котором только это, и все.

А кроме этого, как минимум, должна быть подключена библиотека jQuery.

Comment: Библиотека jQuery подключена, как же без нее. )) Удивительно да?

Comment: Посмотрите: http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/93vbspwq/3/  - ваш пример рабочий.